# Calculate sum of array elements without sum function

Tags: xslt

I am new to xslt. I have a xml file like

```
<EmpCollection>
<Emp>
<Name>Sai</Name>
<Sal>7000</Sal>
</Emp>
<Emp>
<Name>Nari</Name>
<Sal>7400</Sal>
</Emp>
<Emp>
<Name>Hari</Name>
<Sal>9000</Sal>
</Emp>
<Emp>
<Name>Suri</Name>
<Sal>8900</Sal>
</Emp>
</EmpCollection>
```

Now I want to add sum of salaries without using sum() function. 
I want to learn xslt in a clear way:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I. Probably one of the simplest solutions**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="Sal">
  <xsl:param name="pSum" select="0"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="following::Sal[1]">
       <xsl:with-param name="pSum" select="$pSum + ."/>
     </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Sal[not(following::Sal)]">
  <xsl:param name="pSum" select="0"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$pSum + ."/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::Sal[1]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<EmpCollection>
    <Emp>
        <Name>Sai</Name>
        <Sal>7000</Sal>
    </Emp>
    <Emp>
        <Name>Nari</Name>
        <Sal>7400</Sal>
    </Emp>
    <Emp>
        <Name>Hari</Name>
        <Sal>9000</Sal>
    </Emp>
    <Emp>
        <Name>Suri</Name>
        <Sal>8900</Sal>
    </Emp>
</EmpCollection>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
32300
```

---

**II. A more general solution is to use the [FXSL](http://fxsl.sf.net) 2.x [`f:foldl()`](http://fxsl.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fxsl/fxsl-xslt2/f/func-foldl.xsl?revision=1.3&view=markup) function like this:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/" exclude-result-prefixes="f">
   <xsl:import href="../f/func-foldl.xsl"/>
   <xsl:import href="../f/func-Operators.xsl"/>

   <xsl:output  encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of select="f:foldl(f:add(), 0, /*/*/Sal)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this XSLT 2.0 transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the same correct and wanted result is produced**:

```
32300
```

**You can pass any two-argument function as argument to `f:foldl()` and produce the solutions of different problems**.

For example, passing `f:mult()` instead of `f:add()` (and changing the "zero" argument to `1`) produces the product of the salaries:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/" exclude-result-prefixes="f">
   <xsl:import href="../f/func-foldl.xsl"/>
   <xsl:import href="../f/func-Operators.xsl"/>

   <xsl:output  encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of select="f:foldl(f:mult(), 1, /*/*/Sal)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**The result of applying this transformation to the same XML document is now the product of all `Sal` elements**:

```
4.14918E15
```

---

**III. In XSLT 3.0 (XPath 3.0) one can use the standard [`fold-left()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-fold-left) or  [`fold-right()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-fold-right) function in exactly the same way as in the previous solution**.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably more elegant ways (and I guess `sum()` :) but the following works, by ['folding' siblings with addition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657749/recursively-apply-templates-to-result-tree-in-xslt-constant-folding). The termination condition is the last sibling (i.e. with no following nodes)

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/EmpCollection">
        <result>Result Is : <xsl:apply-templates select="Emp[1]"/>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Emp[following-sibling::Emp]">
        <xsl:variable name="salThis">
            <xsl:value-of select="Sal"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="salOthers">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Emp[position()=1]"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="$salThis + $salOthers"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--Termination - the last employee just returns its salary value-->
    <xsl:template match="Emp[not(following-sibling::Emp)]">
        <xsl:value-of select="Sal"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Gives the Result:

```
<result>Result Is : 32300</result>
```

**Edit**

After reading your question again, I guess this isn't a code golf question?
The below is a more simple way to do this with hard coded element names, which instructs the processor to add together the salaries of the named employees:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/EmpCollection">
        <result>
            Result Is : <xsl:value-of select="Emp[Name='Sai']/Sal + Emp[Name='Nari']/Sal + Emp[Name='Hari']/Sal + Emp[Name='Suri']/Sal"/>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which should then lead easily to understand what `sum()` is doing:

```
<xsl:template match="/EmpCollection">
    <result>
        Result Is : <xsl:value-of select="sum(Emp/Sal)"/>
    </result>
</xsl:template>
```

**Edit**

Count is simply:

```
<xsl:template match="/EmpCollection">
    <result>
        <xsl:text>Count Is : </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(Emp)"/>
    </result>
</xsl:template>
```

Doing this without `count()` isn't as simple. Note that `xsl:variable`s cannot be changed once assigned (immutable). So the following doesn't work at all.

```
<xsl:template match="/EmpCollection">
    <xsl:variable name="count" select="0" />
    <xsl:for-each select="Emp">
        <!--NB : You can't do this. Variables are immutable - XSLT is functional -->
        <xsl:variable name="count" select="$count + 1"></xsl:variable>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <result>
        Result Is : <xsl:value-of select="$count"/>
    </result>
</xsl:template>
```

So you could 'loop' through all the nodes, and then use `position()` to determine if this is the last node in the sequence. (Note that we've used `for-each`, but in practice it is better to use use `apply-template`)

```
<xsl:template match="/EmpCollection">
    <result>
        <xsl:text>Count Is : </xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="Emp">
            <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
                <xsl:number value="position()" format="1" />
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </result>
</xsl:template>
```

[:(](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem)

Comment: Thanks but I am not able to get the answer. There is two xsl:value-of($salThis + $salOthers, $Sal) nodes are there in your first answer. Am I Right? Happy if you provide answer with count nodes like the way we deal with arrays. Not using siblings:)

Comment: @Sai - updated for count. Note that this isn't really how SO works though - ideally you should ask specific questions which have a definite answer. I would suggest reading through [Dimitre's posts](http://stackoverflow.com/users/36305/dimitre-novatchev) - he is an xslt guru who gives detailed explanations.

Comment: @Sai the 'sum without using sum()' uses recursion (folding), and after each 'call' it captures the result in a variable. It isn't trivial at all.

Comment: Thanks... I am new to SO. I will remember your comments.